# How to find volume of $\iint_D \sqrt{x^2+y^2}dA$ without computing integral?

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have $\iint_D \sqrt{x^2+y^2}dA$ where $D$ is a disc with a radius of 3. After changing to polar form we obtain the integral  $\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{3}_0 r^2drd\theta$. Since this is a rather trivial integral to compute I will leave out the computations and just give the answer of $18\pi.$

Since a double integral represents volume how would you go about finding $\iint_D \sqrt{x^2+y^2}dA$ without computing the integral?

Since volume ($V$) of a cylinder is $V = \pi r^2h$ what would the height be as I dont see it defined anywhere in the region $D$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be a cylinder minus the volume of a cone, both with height $z = \max_{D}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 3$

$$V = \pi r^2 h - \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h = \frac{2}{3} \pi 3^3 = 18\pi$$

Comment: $+1$; I was just about to say that

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense now.